# What is difference between using inline spread operator in setState and declaring new object outside of method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was getting some weird behaviour in my app for selecting services on a page.  The full logic isn't relevant as I managed to fix it but I don't understand why what I changed fixed it.

I save the selected services in a state variable:

```
const [selectedServices, setSelectedServices] = useState({});
```

I was then in an event handler updating them like so:

```
let newServices = { ...selectedServices, ...toChange };
setSelectedServices(newServices);
```

This gave me weird janky behaviour which usually happens when I am mutating the current state value instead of creating a new object.  I played around with it and changed it to this:

```
setSelectedServices((prev) => { return { ...prev, ...toChange } });
```

This fixed it, it now works as expected but I have no idea why.

`newServices` is created with the spread operator so it should be a new object.  I guess there is some difference with the scoping or something that makes the changes work better but I don't understand it.

Can someone explain to me the difference between assigning in these 2 ways?

Comment: You're using the same spread operator in both cases, they're both creating a new object. [Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) solve problems with stale closures. _"usually happens when I am mutating the current state"_ - don't do that!

Comment: Would probably need to see where the setSelectedServices is called but could be caused by the fact selectedServices is not equal to the exact previous value at the time of calling. Which is solved by functional update.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I'm not mutating on purpose, I'm saying the error resembles when I do it by accident but here I am using spread operator so it was confusing what was actually causing the issue.

Comment: @Ivo It is attached to the change event of a third party component which reads back the selected value in order to update.  I guess it must be some timing issue like you say with when third party code reads the value that functional update fixes.

Is always using functional update best practice?

Comment: If you update a state based on a previous state that's best practice indeed. Not needed when you update a state based on a fully new value.